# How to get difference between 2 lists of string (ignore partial match)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
listA =['set', 'pet', 'get']

listB =['set_tet', 'rgrgrgrg', 'grggrr', 'get']

expected output = ['pet', 'rgrgrgrg', 'grggrr']
```

'set' is partially found in listB, so it is ignored.
'pet' is NOT found in listB, so it is included.
'get' is found in in listB, so it is ignored. 
'set_tet' is NOT included because we previously matched 'set'
'rgrgrgrg' and 'grggrr' is included because it didn't match anything in listA

How do I do this in Python 2.7?

Comment: when you say difference between 2 lists , here it's listB -listA right?

Comment: Why `pet` is not in the expected output?

Comment: arsho, good catch, I updated the output

Comment: lazarus, not exactly. If I did listB - listA, 'set_tet' would show up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the question it seems you are looking for `listB + listA - intersection of listA and listB` where  for intersection it's not necessary to have exact same string it could be substring as well .

you can try the below approach , I have tried it in python 2.7.9

```
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)

# union of setA and setB 
AunionB = setA | setB

# intersection of setA and setB
AinterB = setA & setB

# calculate A union B minus A intersection B
result_set = AunionB - AinterB

# convert to list
result_list = list(result_set)

# now here we have the partial search stings as well i.e.set and set_tet
# we have to omit it from final output

# create a list which will hold partial match
partial_match_candidate = []

# search for partial match in result set list
for i in range(len(result_list)-1):
    # iterate from i+1 to len(result_list)
    for j in range(i+1 , len(result_list)):
        # check if there is partial match
        if result_list[i] in result_list[j] or result_list[j] in result_list[i]:
            partial_match_candidate.append(result_list[i])
            partial_match_candidate.append(result_list[j])


# now we have to candidates to remove i.e. set and set_tet
result_list_filtered = [ val for val in result_list if val not in partial_match_candidate ]
```

Complexity wise, its not best , but I hope it helps.

Comment: not exactly. If I did listB - listA, 'set_tet' would show up

Comment: Thanks. I also updated the problem description to make more sense of this.

Comment: it should work , could you please copy my whole code with the value of listA and listB from question

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ObviousRipeCylinder     forgot to start from i+1 in inner loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191124/discussion-between-lazarus-and-usustarr).

Comment: Some of my elements are like ' "fsf sfsdf" gsd ' Is it possible your code would have issues with that?